# Button not working in the list PHP

Tags: php, button, html-table, popup

Trying to get the pop up to show the data the user click on the button. However only the button at the first row of the table is able to call out the pop up when click on other rows' button it does not respond.

```
$list = '';
$projectName ='';
$budget = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $projectName =$row['projectName'] ;
    $budget = $row['budget'];
    $id = $row['ID'];
    $mile1 = $row['mileStone1'];
    $mile2 = $row['mileStone2'];
    $mile3 = $row['mileStone3'];
    $percent1 = $row['percentage1'];
    $percent2 = $row['percentage2'];
    $percent3 = $row['percentage3'];
    $list .= '<tr><td>'.$projectName.'</td><td>'.$budget.'</td><td>';
    $list .= '<a id="login_a"><button type="button" >View </button></a></td></tr>';
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#login_a").click(function(){
    $("#shadow").fadeIn("normal");
     $("#login_form").fadeIn("normal");
     $("#user_name").focus();
});
$("#cancel_hide").click(function(){
    $("#login_form").fadeOut("normal");
    $("#shadow").fadeOut();
});
});
</script>

<div id="dashboard-content">
<table border=1 >
<tr>
<th>Project Name</th>
<th>Budget</th>
<th> View </th>
</tr>
<?php echo $list?>    
</table>
</div>

<div id="login_form">
<table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th> Project Name </th>
    <td>
    <?php echo $projectName?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th> Budget</th>
    <td> 
    <?php echo $budget?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Stages</th>
    <th>Payment Percentage</th>
    </tr>

    <?php if(!empty($percent2)){ ?>
    <tr>
    <td> 
    <?php echo $mile1;?>
    </td>
    <td>
    <?php echo $percent1;?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if(!empty($percent2)){ ?>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <?php echo $mile2;?>
    </td>
    <td>
    <?php echo $percent2;?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if(!empty($percent3)){ ?>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <?php echo $mile3;?>
    </td>
    <td>
    <?php echo $percent3; ?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </table>
    <div class="err" id="accept"></div>
    <div class="err" id="reject"></div>
    <input type="button" id="cancel_hide" value="Close" />
</div>
```

Comment: You never `echo $list` anywhere.

Comment: Shouldn't you be looping over the results of the query inside your table? Your variables `$budget`, `$mile1`, etc. only contain the values from the last row of the results.

Comment: Sorry forget to paste the echo $list here

Comment: Yeah the values only contain the last row of table... Still trying to find ways like giving it a hidden value. But buttons below the first button does work.

Comment: OK, now you're echoing the button. But there's nothing in there about a popup.

Comment: Probably the problem is that you gave all the buttons the same ID. I assume there's some code you haven't shown that binds a handler to the `login_a` ID. Since IDs are supposed to be unique, this only binds the first one.

Comment: You should use a class instead of ID, and bind the handler to all elements in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs are supposed to be unique, so the selector `$("#login_a")` only matches the first one. You should use a class:

```
$list .= '<a class="login_a"><button type="button" >View </button></a></td></tr>';
```

and then do:

```
$(".login_a").click(function(){
    $("#shadow").fadeIn("normal");
     $("#login_form").fadeIn("normal");
     $("#user_name").focus();
});
```

To get all the data into your table, change your `while` loop to:

```
$list = '';
$projectData = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $projectName =$row['projectName'] ;
    $budget = $row['budget'];
    $projectData[] = $row;
    $list .= '<tr><td>'.$projectName.'</td><td>'.$budget.'</td><td>';
    $list .= '<a class="login_a"><button type="button" >View </button></a></td></tr>';
}
```

Then change the HTML for the table to:

```
<table border=1>
    <?php foreach ($projectData as $proj) {
    <tr>
    <th> Project Name </th>
    <td>
    <?php echo $proj['projectName']?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th> Budget</th>
    <td> 
    <?php echo $proj['budget']?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Stages</th>
    <th>Payment Percentage</th>
    </tr>

    <?php if(!empty($proj['percent2'])){ ?>
    <tr>
    <td> 
    <?php echo $proj['mile1'];?>
    </td>
    <td>
    <?php echo $proj['percent1'];?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if(!empty($proj['percent2'])){ ?>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <?php echo $proj['mile2'];?>
    </td>
    <td>
    <?php echo $proj['percent2'];?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if(!empty($proj['percent3'])){ ?>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <?php echo $proj['mile3'];?>
    </td>
    <td>
    <?php echo $proj['percent3']; ?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php }
    }
    ?>        
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah now the buttons can work. But now is still loading the last row of data

Comment: Like I said above, the `while` loop should be inside the table, or you should be creating array variables in the loop and iterating over them when creating the table.

Comment: Erm... I am not so sure how to implement the while loops inside the html part. Could you give me an example?

Comment: It worked however the pop up is showing every single data on any button i clicked on